# How to create keycloak policy for the Keycloak Authorization

Tags: keycloak

I've created a Client `DemoClient` and in that, I've enabled the `Fine-grained Authorization` option. So now the Authorization tab is visible to me.

In that, I can see the multiple sub-tabs as shown below and I'm having different scopes like `res:create`, `res:update`, `res:delete` etc. and also created the `Client Policy` with name `my_policy` and selected the client as `DemoClient` and associated that Policy with the `Scope Based Permission` **(Image Is available)**

[image]

[image]

As per the above, I've done it. Now my question is that.

I've two users `MANAGER` & `CUSTOMER` and consider I've created one resource **(manager_resource)** and the owner of that resource is `MANAGER User` and shared that resource with `CUSTOMER User` with only `res:create` permission and then I've Evaluate that using `Evaluate Tab` for the verification.

As a user, I've select `CUSTOMER` as a user and Resource as `manager_project`.
[image]

**So now the problem is that it permits all the scope's permission, but I've only associated the `res:create` scope.**

I've also tried with JS Policy, but I don't want to use JS policy for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

How about this approach? pointing the same resource with two resources.
[image]

Customer Resource
[image]

Customer permission
[image]

Customer policy
[image]
Manager Resource
[image]

Manager permission
[image]

Manager policy
[image]

Customer Evaluate
[image]

Customer Result
[image]

Manager Evaluate
[image]

Manager Result
[image]

If try to access by other two scopes by the customer, will DENY.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response, but the problem is that I need to create a separate resource for that if suppose I'm sharing this resource with **1000 user** then for the single resource I need to create 1000 resources? I don't think this is an appropriate solution. And what if I've 1000 resources and 1000 users then? It is very much a hard, complex solution to maintain.

Comment: I've tried with the JS Policy and even that works for me but I don't want to use the JS to create the policy. [JS policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64364399/alternate-option-to-use-some-else-uma-policy-rather-than-js-policy)

Comment: If using the group into customer policy, it addresses the 1000 users. When you create a customer-policy, select "Create with Group" then it's group assign 1000 users.

Comment: I updated my answer images - overview and customer policy